# How to reconnect deepgram socket, once I closed the exisiting socket

Tags: reactjs, websocket, speech-to-text

I've worked on the Deepgram Speech-to-Text client SDK, and I'm using `useEffect` to initialize my connection instance. For the first time, when my component mounts, it works fine for me. If I don't send any data to the event, it automatically closes (as mentioned in their docs, it closes after 12 seconds if no data is sent).

I also discovered the `keepLive()` method in their docs, which also causes the same problem. also  I tried to create an event with `connect()` that triggers when the button is clicked. It creates a new socket instance, but unfortunately, I don't receive the data. To be honest, I don't know what's happening. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this.

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { LiveClient, LiveTranscriptionEvent, LiveTranscriptionEvents, createClient } from '@deepgram/sdk';

const deepgram = createClient(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEEPGRAM_API_KEY || '');
let liveClient: LiveClient;

function useDeepgram(setInputText: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>) {
  const [connectionStatus, setConnectionStatus] = useState<'open' | 'closed'>('closed');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!liveClient) {
      liveClient = deepgram.listen.live({ model: 'nova' });
    }
    liveClient.on(LiveTranscriptionEvents.Open, () => {
      setConnectionStatus('open');
      liveClient.keepAlive();
      liveClient.on(LiveTranscriptionEvents.Transcript, (data: LiveTranscriptionEvent) => {
     
        if (data.type === 'Results') {
          setInputText((prev) => `${prev} ${data.channel.alternatives[0].transcript}`);
        }
      });
      liveClient.on(LiveTranscriptionEvents.Close, () => {
        setConnectionStatus('closed');
      });
    });
  }, []);

  const disconnect = useCallback(() => {
    setConnectionStatus('closed');
    liveClient.finish();
  }, []);

  const sendData = useCallback(
    (chunk: Blob) => {
      liveClient.getReadyState();
      if (connectionStatus === 'open') {
        liveClient.send(chunk);
      }
    },
    [connectionStatus]
  );
  return { connectionStatus, sendData, disconnect };
}
export default useDeepgram;
```